How to untangle the ODE $\frac{dx}{dt} = c + \frac{px}{l_0 + pt}$?
In working on this problem, I came up with the following differential equation:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = c + \frac{px}{l_0 + pt}
$$
where $x$ is the dependent variable, $t$ the independent, and all others constants.  However, I'm at a loss as to how I might solve this equation.
How can I approach this differential equation?

It's a linear inhomogeneous differential equation.

Are you aware of the integrating factor method?

We can rearrange to get
$\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{p}{l_0+pt}x=c$.
Now we multiply both sides by $(l_0+pt)^{-1}$ (this is known as an integrating factor) to get
$(l_0+pt)^{-1}\frac{dx}{dt}-p(l_0+pt)^{-2}x=c(l_0+pt)^{-1}$.
The reason we did this is because now the left hand side is simply the derivative of $(l_0+pt)^{-1}x$ (check!). So integrating both sides, we find
$(l_0+pt)^{-1}x = \frac{c}{p}\ln(l_0+pt)+k$.

The ODE is
$$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=\dfrac{c\ell_0+cpt+px}{\ell_0+pt}$$
We can make a change of coordinates in order for the quotient to become homogeneous: $\xi=x-x_0$ and $\eta=t-t_0$, where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are the coordinates of the point where the lines from the numerator and denominator intersect. Let's find the intersection point first:
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&c\ell_0+cpt+px=0\implies x_0=0\\
&\ell_0+pt=0\implies t_0=-\dfrac{\ell_0}{p}
\end{aligned}\right\}\implies \left\{\begin{aligned}
&x=\xi\\
&t=\eta-\dfrac{\ell_0}{p}
\end{aligned}\right\}\implies \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=\dfrac{\mathrm d\xi}{\mathrm d\eta}$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d\xi}{\mathrm d\eta}=\dfrac{cp\eta+p\xi}{p\eta}$$
and making the substitution $\xi=u(\eta)\eta$ we obtain
$$\eta\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm d\eta}+u=c+u\implies \int\mathrm du=c\int\dfrac{\mathrm d\eta}{\eta}\implies u=c\ln(A\eta)$$
Substituting $u$ and reverting the $\xi$ and $\eta$ changes of coordinate we arrive at
$$\boxed{x(t)=c\left(t+\dfrac{\ell_0}{p}\right)\ln\left[A\left(t+\dfrac{\ell_0}{p}\right)\right]}$$

Hint: You can try to convert this into the form $Mdt+Ndx=0$, and try to find some integrating factor $\mu$ such that the differential equation $\mu Mdt+\mu Ndx=0$ is exact.
Suppose it is, then you will have:
$$\frac{\partial{(\mu M)}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{(\mu N)}}{\partial{t}}$$
Assuming your function $\mu$ is independent of $x$, this simplifies to:
$$\frac{1}{\mu}\frac{d\mu}{dt}=\frac{1}{N}\Big(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\Big)$$
which gives:
$$\mu=ke^{\int{\frac{1}{N}\Big(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\Big)dt}}$$
Where $k$ is some constant. Thus you need to verify that $\frac{1}{N}\Big(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}\Big)$ is purely a function of $t$. Once done with that, you can multiply your integrating factor to your equation to make it exact and solve it further.
